# Do we need to consider bundling and minification for the css, js in case we have caching enabled for these static resources?

Tags: caching, bundling-and-minification

Can anyone please help me to know whether it is really necessary to bundle and minify the static resources like js,css, images in case we have already enabled client side caching.

Please help me to know your thoughts on the above.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling & Minification brings a significant amount of performance improvements to your web app. Below are few pros I can think of:

- Content will be delivered to the client in fewer number of requests (bundled content) as opposed to multiple async requests to load content(js/css)
- Minification will reduce the size of the content files which helps in optimizing it. It also helps in uglify the script so that it's hard to understand.